# Fundamental group of a space obtained from identifying pairs of points

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Suppose there exists two copies of $S^1$, and 2 points on each $S^1$, say $a_1$ and $b_1$ on one copy and $a_2$ and $b_2$ on the other copy. If the points $a_i's$ are identified and $b_i's$ are identified with each other, then what will be the fundamental group of the resulting space.

I tried attaching the points $a_i$ with a line say A, and $b_i$ with a line say B. Then since this is a contractible $X\simeq X/A$. This gives $S^1 \vee S^1$ with two points from each circle identified. I would appreciate any help on how to proceed from here

Comment: You could think about the resulting space as a graph and use that interpretation. Alternatively try to visualise a (sequence of) homotopy(ies) which turn the space into a wedge of circles (you'll find more than two circles) and proceed from there.

Comment: If I contract $A$ and call the intersection point as $a_0$, then I proceed by contracting $b_1$, $a_0$ and $b_2$ to get 3 $S^1$ wedged at a point. Will that do?

Comment: Sounds about right